Given a 2-player zero-sum game in EFG, find a pure Nash equilibrium (given that one exists)
Say we want to find a pure Nash equilibrium of a 2-player zero-sum (2P0S) game. A pure equilibrium does not exist for all games, so let's consider the setting where we are promised that such an equilibrium exists.
If you are given a 2P0S game in extensive form (EFG), you can compute a Nash equilibrium using polynomial time in the size of the game tree, by constructing a linear program. However, this Nash equilibrium may not be pure.
If we specifically want a pure equilibrium, can we still do it in polynomial time? How?
(The paper "Pure Nash Equilibria: Hard and Easy Games" (Gottlob et al., 2005) describes hardness and tractability results but doesn't seem to consider extensive form games. "New complexity results about Nash equilibria" (Conitzer & Sandholm) describes hardness results for Markov games and Bayesian games but doesn't seem to consider the 2P0S setting.)

Can you be more precise about the representation of the input? Is it complete information?

@usul The input is given in extensive form (EFG), which I believe means that it is complete information.

It is straight forward to check whether a give pair of strategies for the two players constitute a pure NE.  Why not try all possible pairs of strategies? One doesn't need zero sum for this. And this works for any fixed # of players, no?

@ChandraChekuri Here, I'm asking if the game is given in extensive form (EFG), i.e. it's a sequential game where the game tree is given. The number of pure strategies is thus exponential in the size of the game tree.

It is NP-Hard to find a pure Nash equilibrium in a 2P0S game given in extensive form, even if one is promised to exist.
It is NP-Hard to decide if a pure Nash equilibrium exists in a 2P0S game given in extensive form. This is a result in "Perfect Recall and Pruning in Games with Imperfect Information", by Jean R. S. Blair, David Mutchler, Michael van Lent (1996).
Section 4.2 in that paper reduces 3-PARTITION to deciding if a pure Nash exists in a 2P0S game.
Section 4.3 states the corollary "Given a zero-sum, perfect-recall game in which a pure-strategy equilibrium point exists, it is NP-hard to find such an equilibrium point", but the proof is in a separate paper which doesn't seem to be on the internet.
